# Rounded brackets around a table (matrix)

Tags: html, css

I have a simple matrix with some input boxes in that I've created using MathML. It works great in Firefox but not Chrome and I'd like to recreate the same sort of thing using just HTML (a table) and CSS such that it works with more browsers.

Here's a link to a screenshot of the intended effect, since I can't post images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iki6d.png

**Working MathML snippet:**

```css
input {
  width: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input + input {
  margin-right: 2em;
}
input:first-child {
  margin-left: 1em !important;
}
```

```html
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <semantics>
    <mrow>
      <mo>{</mo>
      <mtable columnalign="center center center" rowspacing="1ex" displaystyle="false">
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <mi>
              <input type="text">
            </mi>
          </mtd>
          <mtd>
            <mi>
              <input type="text">
            </mi>
          </mtd>
          <mtd>
            <mi>
              <input type="text">
            </mi>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <mi>
              <input type="text">
            </mi>
          </mtd>
          <mtd>
            <mi>
              <input type="text">
            </mi>
          </mtd>
          <mtd>
            <mi>
              <input type="text">
            </mi>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <mi>
              <input type="text">
            </mi>
          </mtd>
          <mtd>
            <mi>
              <input type="text">
            </mi>
          </mtd>
          <mtd>
            <mi>
              <input type="text">
            </mi>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
      </mtable>
      <mo>}</mo>
    </mrow>
  </semantics>
</math>
```

My initial thought was to use the `border-radius` property and set the left and right borders on the table. There's a working snippet below, but I don't like how the top and bottom of the brackets turned out compared to the original MathML code. The lines are noticeably thinner at the top and bottom of the matrix when using the border-radius approach and seem to 'fade out'.

**First attempt snippet using <table> and `border-radius`:**

```css
input {
  width: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
td:first-child input {
  margin-left: 1em !important;
}
td:last-child input {
  margin-right: 1em !important;
}
table {
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried using CSS 2D transforms and actual text to achieve the same effect, but it didn't turn out particularly well.

**Experiment using CSS transforms and <table>:**

```css
input {
  width: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
td:first-child input {
  margin-left: 1em !important;
}
td:last-child input {
  margin-right: 1em !important;
}
table {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span {
  font-family: 'Latin Modern Math';
  transform: scale(2, 4);
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span>(</span>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><span>)</span>
```

Is there any way I can more closely match the original behavior of the MathML code? I was wondering if an SVG-based solution might be better.

I know the MathML code renders the brackets using the Latin Modern Math font but I'm unsure how I can stretch the brackets to surround the table (regardless of its contents).

Comment: I didn't tag this with mathml since it's not really central to the question - the MathML code is merely there as a reference to show what I want to achieve. That said, I'm new to asking on SO so I might be completely wrong/not understand the purpose of tags yet.

Comment: What's wrong with your first attempt?  It looks correct to me?

Comment: @Brian It's not *too* bad but if you look at the tips of the brackets they don't look quite as well defined as the original - they sort of fade out and lose thickness. Maybe I'm being picky but to me the MathML version looks much more like actual brackets than my attempt.

If it doesn't look like I can improve much on that, I'll probably end up using it. I'd prefer to use the actual font, though - probably better for accessibility purposes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make two images of brackets (one left, one right) and set their height to 100%. Through this you can circumvent using real text (and with it the `font-size` property).

Then set the container to `position: relative` and the images to `position: absolute; left(/right): 0px; top: 0px; height:100%;`. The  should fit in between if you write `position: absolute; left:`width of your left bracket`; right:`width of your right bracket`;`.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: I think I'll be using this approach with two SVG images and use the text tool in inkscape to create brackets using the MathML font before converting to path. Thanks!